# Looking for something to replace INTERSECT in ISQL

Tags: intersect, isql, in-subquery

I am trying to construct a query to handle multiple filters in ISQL.  I have a query that provides the answers I need when I'm using MSSQL, but it uses the INTERSECT command, which appears not to be present in ISQL.

I have the following data:

| ItemID | Label | ItemGroupID_1 | ItemGroupID_2 | ItemGroupID_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Champagne Jean Pernet Cuvee | WI | Sparkling | White |
| 2 | Champagne Jean Pernet Millesime 2008 | WI | Sparkling | White |
| 3 | Champagne Jean Pernet Millesime 2009 | WI | Sparkling | White |
| 4 | Chateau de Montmirail Gigondas Cuvee 2017 | WI | Still | Blue |
| 5 | Chateau de Montmirail Gigondas Cuvee 2018 | WI | Still | Red |
| 6 | Chateau de Montmirail Cotes du Rhone 2015 | WI | Still | Red |
| 7 | Toutigeac Bordeaux Blanc 2018 | WI | Still | Black |
| 8 | Toutigeac Bordeaux Blanc 2019 | WI | Still | White |
| 9 | Domaine Feuillat-Juillot Montagny 2017 | WI | *Null* | Black |
| 10 | Domaine Alphonse Dolly Pouilly Fume 2017 | WI | Still | White |

I want users to be able to select from multiple filters to find, for example, all of the items where ItemGroupID_1 = 'WI', ItemGroupID_2 = 'Still', and ItemGroupID_3 = 'Red'. I have been told by the programmers that I cannot do a simple query like

`SELECT ItemID from Items where ItemGroupID_1 = 'WI' and ItemGroupID_2 = 'Still' and ItemGroupID_3 = 'Red'`

In MSSQL, this works:

`SELECT ItemID AS A FROM Items WHERE ItemGroupID_1 = 'WI'
INTERSECT
SELECT ItemID AS A FROM Items WHERE ItemGroupID_2 = 'Still'
INTERSECT
SELECT ItemID AS A FROM Items WHERE ItemGroupID_3 = 'Red'`

The problem is that the query needs to run in ISQL.  And it doesn't look like ISQL has the INTERSECT command.  (See [Sybase's woefully inadequate technical reference](https://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.12.0.1/uladmin/ua-sql-statements.html).)

However, UNION does work in ISQL.  Fortunately, A AND B is the same thing as NOT-A NOR NOT-B.

In MSSQL this works and returns the results I want:

`SELECT ItemID, Label, ItemGroupID_1, ItemGroupID_2, ItemGroupID_3 AS A FROM Items WHERE ItemID NOT IN
(SELECT ItemID AS A FROM Items WHERE  ItemGroupID_1 <> 'WI' or ItemGroupID_1 is null
UNION
SELECT ItemID AS A FROM Items WHERE  ItemGroupID_2 <> 'Still' or ItemGroupID_2 is null
UNION
SELECT ItemID AS A FROM Items WHERE  ItemGroupID_3 <> 'Red' or ItemGroupID_3 is null)`

The subquery works in ISQL and returns everything I don't want.  But when I add in the statement `SELECT ItemID, Label, ItemGroupID_1, ItemGroupID_2, ItemGroupID_3 AS A FROM Items WHERE ItemID NOT IN`  I get:

> Could not execute statement.
>
> [UltraLite Database] Syntax error near 'UNION' [SQL Offset 132]
>
> SQLCODE=-131, ODBC 3 State='42000'
>
> Line 3

I came across the ISQL command EXISTS and NOT EXISTS, but NOT EXISTS returns no values.

Comment: which Sybase RDBMS product (ASE? IQ? SQLAnywhere? Advantage?) and version are you using? also consider ... `isql` is a front-end/client tool and has no concept of what is (not) a valid `SQL` command; `isql` submits the query to the database engine and it's the database engine that validates/runs the query in question; you'll get the same issues/errors if you use `isql`, `dbisql`, `DBArtisan`, `RabidSQL`, custom `C/C++/perl/python/etc` or any other front-end/client

Comment: as for the link to the 'woefully inadequate technical reference' ... that points to a subset of the SQL available in the `SQLAnywhere/Ultralite` product **and** it's for a version of the software that's at least 10 yrs old; even this old version of `SQLAnywhere` **does** support [intersect](https://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.12.0.1/dbreference/intersect-statement.html); `SQLAnywhere` (and `IQ` since it uses `SQLAnywhere` as a front-end) have pretty good support for ANSI SQL 'standards'; `ASE` on the other hand is 'woefully' lacking in ANSI SQL support

Comment: there are lots of differences in the various Sybase RDBMS products (and versions) so finding a solution to your current issue brings us back to my original question: which Sybase RDBMS product, and version, are you using?